# Why is sandboxing untrusted interpreted code difficult

Tags: security, sandbox

This is a theoretical question of an empirical observation, which is not directly code related, but I think is of practical importance.

The failure and deprecation of `rexec` in Python, the hoops people jump through the sandbox their Javascript (for example with Google Caja), sandboxing code seems to be quite a challenge.

Why is this the case? It seems to me that any interpreted language is "by default" sandboxed: it can only change the internal state of the interpreter (by creating variables, calling methods, etc), and not do anything outside the interpreter. In order for any interpreted code to have any effect outside of the interpreter (for example for printing) the interpreter needs to expose hooks the interpreted code can use to cause the interpreter to do things in the "outside" world.

If that is the case, sandboxing untrusted code should be as simple as limiting what hooks you expose to it, which should not be difficult, if my above logic is correct and the hooks had to be specially added after the fact on top of the complete, working language.

Obviously that is not the case, because rexec *is* dead and Google Caja *does* exist. Something in my above description must be mistaken or inaccurate. What is it?

Comment: The issue isn't so much sandboxing the interpreter from the operating system. It's sandboxing one part of the script from another. How do you make sure one script doesn't attack a global variable used by another script? How do you prevent one script from impersonating another script?

Comment: I suppose my point is that if you are already interpreting the script, firing up a second interpreter for a different script (or even just firing up a new context for the current interpreter, sans all the important variables, data, OS hooks, etc.) shouldn't be that hard. Is that assumption wrong?

Comment: Usually you want some degree of interaction between the two scripts. (Otherwise, you'd just run two different programs entirely.) For example, a Web page might load an element into the DOM, and that element may come with its own script, and you want that script to be able to interact with the DOM, which is a global variable to the script environment. The problem is allowing the two scripts to interact to the degree you want, without letting them interact in ways you don't want.